# How to tell Eclipse that folder was moved

Tags: android, eclipse

I have moved (the content of) the `src` folder of my Android project to `src/main/java` because I want to use gradle. So far no problem.

But then I moved the `res` folder to `src/main/res` because I want to use a different `res` folder in `src/debug/res` for my debug builds. Now Eclipse gives me that error:

```
ERROR: resource directory '/.../MyProject/res' does not exist
```

How can I tell Eclipse that the folder was moved? I already moved the folder back and then again to the new location using right-click -> Refactor -> Move. So Eclipse should know where the `res` folder is.

Comment: IIRC, Eclipse doesn't support the Android/Gradle package structure. Gradle, however, has configuration options where you can tell it to use your project structure, so there's no need to try and convert it: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure

Comment: I wanted to use the debug/res folder as an overlay to the main/res folder and thought that Gradle would need that folder structure for doing so. I moved the res folder back and changed the build.gradle file as described on your linked page. That way it works for Eclipse and Gradle. Thank you!